# How do I save state of animation in android, onPause() method?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate, onpause

I have 3 activities, each activity is a page in a book, it has some animations.

When i press on image, it changes to another.
I press next arrow and go to the next activity, if i go back - the app calls `onCreate()` automatically and my changed image is gone!
**How do I keep/save the state of the previous activity without loosing it?**

[image: d]
on the image below, the elipse is clicked and turns green, then i press "next" arrow, when i try to go back, the changed state is gone